# How do I tell Entity Framework to allow SQL Server to provide a defined default value for a field?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, default-value

I used the following SQL script to enable setting current time in a field, when a new row is added to a table:

```
ALTER TABLE [Items] ADD CONSTRAINT DF_Items DEFAULT GETDATE() FOR [CreationDate]
```

Now I am using Entity Framework to work with this table, and add new rows to it. What I want to do is allow that specific column to receive its value from SQL Server itself, and not have to provide the value myself.
Setting that specific column's value to `Nothing` in Visual Basic fills the field with `DateTime.MinValue`, which is not what I want (and SQL Server doesn't support, by the way).

What changes do I have to make to make this work?

Comment: Change from Entity Framework to a sensible solution :) heheh

Comment: Well Andomar, that would be a very dramatic change. I was looking for a smaller one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must set `StoreGeneratedPattern` in EDMX designer (or `DatabaseGeneratedOption` in code first) to `Identity` for that date property. EF always sends .NET default value for not filled property which is not store generated. Setting the pattern to `Identity` will tell EF that value is generated in DB during insert and it will requery its value. If you change the pattern from default value you will not be able to set the property in your application.

Comment: Yes, that is supposed to solve the problem. But unfortunately I got the same exception again although I set StoreGeneratedPattern to Identity. The exception again tells me that SQL can't accept #12:00:00 AM# as a valid value, meaning EF is still sending the .NET default to SQL. Anything else I should be careful with?

Comment: Open EDMX file as XML and check that the pattern is correctly set in both CSDL part and SSDL part of the mapping file.