# Linq To Sql : SQL Default Value overridden

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have read several post around the problem but found not solution to the issue I'm facing with.

My entity model contains several date properties whose values I need to be set at SQL server level. Here's an example:

```
 [Column(IsDbGenerated = true)]
 public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

DateCreated is a 'date' type on SQL Server, and its default value is GETDATE().

```
[DateCreated]      DATE           DEFAULT (getdate()) NOT NULL,
```

As a matter of fact saving a new record (without passing any DateCreated value) results in '1/1/0001' (i.e. null datetime) value being inserted.
It looks like Linq overrides default server GETDATE() value, forcing a 'null' value to be written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity`.

Here are two links that explain further:

- [Entity Framework Code First Data Annotations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591583(v=vs.113).aspx)
- [How do I tell Entity Framework to allow SQL Server to provide a defined default value for a field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11173162/how-do-i-tell-entity-framework-to-allow-sql-server-to-provide-a-defined-default)

Comment: Thanks paulsm4, DatabaseGeneratedOption, as per Ladislav's post solved but: 
1. I couldn't chose 'Identity' (more relevant to me as this data is not to be later updated) as I was getting 'Validation failed for one or more entities' error, hence I had to switch to 'Computed' to remove the error but I don't quite understand why.
2. What is it '[Column(IsDbGenerated = true)]' supposed to be used for then?